# LINQ and Nhibernate: create an Expression using a model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate

I am getting started with LINQ and NHibernate, can you help me get oriented please:

I need to pass a lambda statement to nhibernate .QueryOver() which is conditional based on a property on my model:

```
if (model.PropertyA != String.Empty) {
    var searchResults = nhibSession.QueryOver<type>(x => 
                                             x.propA == model.PropertyA)
                                   .List();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this using a C# Expression instead of a lambda statement?  How do I create an Expression using model.PropertyA?  Do I use Expression.Property() or Expression.Field()?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I create an Expression using model.PropertyA?

I suspect you should be using [`Expression.Constant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.constant.aspx) - even though it doesn't "feel" like a constant in the normal sense, it's constant *for that expression* as the model isn't part of the input to the expression.

```
Expression foo = Expression.Constant(model.PropertyA);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Jon.  How do I access a property on the ParameterExpression?

Comment: @jjirka: Use `Expression.Property`, passing in the `ParameterExpression` as the target.

Comment: Sorry, I have                    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "x");  And I am trying to access a column on it like this:  var exp = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(string).GetProperty("PropertyA"));

Comment: @jjirka: Well `string` doesn't have a `PropertyA` property, does it? It sounds like you shouldn't be using `typeof(string)` there. Note that you can just pass in the property name, you don't *have* to resolve it to a `PropertyInfo`.